# Bootstrap is not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i tried to run my design to the developer tools on chrome as a mobile but the bootstrap is not working. Can someone give me ideas why the bootstrap is not working on mobile?

here is the picture when i tried to run on mobile.
[image]

and this when i run on desktop it worked i don't know why not on mobile.

[image]

here is my media queries.

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
.img-responsive{
 width: 300px;
height:50px;
padding-left:50px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 376px) {
.img-responsive{
 width: 220px;
 height:50px;
 padding-left: 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 286px) {
.img-responsive{
 width: 180px;
 height:50px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 }
.footer{
 height: auto;
 }
 h4{
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 }
 }
```

Comment: the width is 286px sir. wait i add the media queries. i will update the question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are probably missing the **viewport meta tag** in the html head:

Viewport is the **user's visible area of a web page**. Using `width=device-width` you need to set the width to device width you are viewing in like mobile or tablet or desktop.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**Refer this link :** **[Viewport meta tag](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)**

**[What is Viewport?.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)**

Comment: Hello sir! It works!  :) Can you explain me what is viewport?

Comment: What is the use of css in viewport?

Comment: nethken: you mean @viewport in css?.

Comment: @nethken: viewport is user's visible area of the page/ area of the window in which a web content can be seen

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning...

The viewport also has to be set on any "parent" pages (if running in iframes), and  master pages.

Comment: This might work better as a comment on the accepted answer or editing the existing answer to include this note

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30348587)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the viewport to make your website look good on all devices:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Please, leave your note as comment of original answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30788792)