# Bootstrap media query

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Twitter bootstrap css col-sm-* has media query

```
media(min-width:768px)
```

but this media query works in small screens smaller than 768. I tried to find the solution but no help. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: can you explain more about your issuse it is not clear...

Comment: [You are probably missing the viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813919/bootstrap-is-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: I think it should be "@media (max-width:767px)"